# regular expression find/replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to replace all of the php short tags to full blown ones.

Example source text:

```
<a href="<?=$baseurl?>random/<?php echo $offset+$per_page; ?>" class="arrows right" <?php echo $displayright; ?>></a>
```

Expected final result:

```
<a href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>random/<?php echo $offset+$per_page; ?>" class="arrows right" <?php echo $displayright; ?>></a>
```

I got as far as this:

Find what: `<?=(.*)?>`

Replace with: `<?php echo \1; ?>`

But the result is:

```
<a href="<?php echo $baseurl?>random/<?php echo $offset+$per_page; ?>" class="arrows right" <?php echo $displayright; ; ?>></a>
```

So it doesn't really work when there are multiple php opening and closing tags on one line.

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Notepad++ regular expressions are rather broken anyway... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because the `*` operator is **greedy** and will try to match everything up to the final `?`. You can fix this by matching everything except the `?` in the closing tag:

Find what: `<?=([^?]*)?>`

Replace with: `<?php echo \1; ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the Search for field:

```
<\?=([^?]+)\?>
```

And this in the replacement field:

```
<?php echo \1; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use *, Notepad++ matches as much as it can, so you need to tell it what you don't want to match so it stops without finding the whole line:

Find:   `<?=([^?]*)?>`

Replace: `<?php echo \1; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Using * in your regex makes it "greedy" and you don't want that.  You want the first occurrence of ?> to be matched and not the last. Also, the ? character is special in regexes so you need to escape it too:

```
<\?=([^?]+)\?>
```